# Is it possible to use pandas in Scrapy?

Tags: python, pandas, scrapy

I'm curious if pandas can be used in scrapy in conjunction with beautifulsoup to be able to extract data tables, and if so, how can it be done?

I just started learning about scrapy and wanted to see if I can use it to scrape websites with Covid-19 charts just to see if I can collect all the data needed from just the tables.

```
import scrappy
from bs4 import beautifulsoup
import pandas as pd


class Covid_Crawler(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Covid_Crawler"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/countries-where-coronavirus-has-spread/'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        #filename = "test.html"
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
        yield{
            "table": soup.find('table')
        }
        df = pd.read_html(soup.find('table'))
        print(df)
```

For context to my logic, I wrote a simple scraper that could go to a website and pull the table and place it in a xlsx sheet for review

```
 url="https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/countries-where-coronavirus-has-spread/"
 # Make a GET request to fetch the raw HTML content
 html_content = requests.get(url).text

 # Parse the html content
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")



 try:
     covid_table = soup.find('table')
     df = pd.read_html(str(covid_table))[0]
     print(df)
     df.to_excel("test4.xlsx")


 except:
     print("No tables found")
```

And was able to the results of the table

```
               Country     Cases  Deaths             Region
 0       United States  15810437  296568      North America
 1               India   9762326  141735               Asia
 2              Brazil   6730118  179032      South America
 3              Russia   2541199   44718             Europe
 4              France   2324216   56648             Europe
 ..                ...       ...     ...                ...
 214        MS Zaandam         9       2                NaN
 215  Marshall Islands         4       0  Australia/Oceania
 216   Wallis & Futuna         3       0  Australia/Oceania
 217             Samoa         2       0  Australia/Oceania
 218           Vanuatu         1       0  Australia/Oceania

 [219 rows x 4 columns]
```

I want to be able to replicate these results, but have it move through multiple pages on the website and collect these tables

Edit: I now have it doing what I wanted, so now how do I go from page to page?

Comment: yes, you can use `pandas` in `Scrapy`. And I don't understand what problem you have with this. If you get error message then show it in question.

Comment: BTW: you have wrong indentation and you use `pandas` outside `parse()` - so you try to use `soup` in `read_html` when `soup` doesn't exist.

Comment: The indentation was an accident, should be corrected now.

Comment: BTW: instead of function `start_requests` you can use list `start_urls = [...your urls...]` and it will do the same as you do in `start_requests`.

Comment: If you want to visit pages which are not connected by links then you have to add them manually to `start_urls` or use them in your `start_requests()`. But if you want to go from one page to another using link on first page then you have to scrapy functions (or Beautifulsoup functions) to get links on current page and add them to queue using `yield Request()`. If you will use scrapy function then you may also use `follow()` like in first example on [main page of Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)